# Gravity Forms Validation with Business Tax ID Number

Tags: php, forms, validation, gravity, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a Gravity Form that has a form field for a business tax number. I need to validate this field so that the user can only type in a number in the format XX-XXXXXXX. I'm having some trouble with this because I know HTML/CSS but don't have a clue about PHP. Here's the code I have, is it correct? (It's for form ID #1, form field ID #3):

```
<?php

add_filter("gform_field_validation_1_3", "custom_validation", 10, 4);

function custom_validation($result, $value, $form, $field){

if(!preg_match(‘/^\d{2}-\d{7}$/‘, $value)){
    $result["is_valid"] = false;
    $result["message"] = "Please enter a valid tax number";
}

return $result;

}

?>
```

Also, I'm trying to include it in my functions.php for my wordpress theme but it's breaking the site and showing a blank page. It's probably something really stupid, since PHP confuses me. any reason why this code can't be added to a wordpress functions.php?

Answer (score 1):

No need to add custom code. Gravity forms will handle it for you. Create the field as a text field. Make it required. Chose 'Custom Input mask' Set the mask to 99-9999999. You're good to go.